# How do i get all inputs from div except empry values for jspdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Im using jspdf to create a pdf from some divs i have.
There are a lot of inputs,some of them are required,some are not. I need to get *only* the values that are not empty from my input fields,but i can't make it work,even tho im 90% sure my code should work fine. Here it is:

```
  var doc = new jsPDF();
    var i=1;
    $("div#home :input[type=text]").each(function(){
      i++;
 var input = $(this);
 if(input.val().lenght>0){
   console.log(input);    
 var text = input.attr('placeholder')+':  '+input.val();
 
 



doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.text(10, (i*8) + (10),text+"\n");
 } 


});
doc.save('a4.pdf')
```

The code above does not work. when i use it,i get nothing for the pdf. if i remove the `.lenght>0` it works,but it gets all the empty values so my pdf goes with a lot of blank spaces. i have tried using `input.val().>0`,`input.val().!==''`,and none of them works,they all give me the same result.
How can i check properly if my input fields are not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own problem. The code is fine,the problem was in my auto increment variable "i".

```
      var doc = new jsPDF();
    var i=1;
    $("div#home :input[type=text]").each(function(){
      i++;
 var input = $(this);
 if(input.val().lenght>0){
   console.log(input);    
 var text = input.attr('placeholder')+':  '+input.val();
 
 



doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.text(10, (i*8) + (10),text+"\n");
 } 


});
doc.save('a4.pdf')
```

As you can see above,my variable was outside the "each" loop that was looping trough the non-empty values of my input fields. The loop was fine,but as the "i++" variable was out of the loop,it was couting empty values and giving me blank spaces between the non-empty ones.  So the only thing i needed to do was to move my "i" inside the loop. Yes,pretty stupdid error,but it took me hours to find out.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a typo:

`input.val().lenght`

should be this instead:

`input.val().length`

You should see an error message in your browser console, because `length` was misspelled.

Comment: This typo was probably because this was my try number 1.000000. I corrected it,and it is still not working. It gives me blank spaces between my inputs with values,where sould be none...

Comment: Okay can you show that as well? You can make your code a runnable example with the `[<>]` button. Just remove unneccessary code. Maybe you want to trim? `var text = input.attr('placeholder')+': '+input.val().trim();`.. please update your original post, thanks.